# Error: Unable to load dynamic library &#39;C:\PHP\ext\php_sqlsrv.dll

Tags: php, html, sql-server, iis

I have tried all the options I could so far find regarding to .dll error but it has not been able to resolve my issue.

Please does any one have an idea of how I can get php to load these dynamic libraries. I am using php 5.3.18, IIS 7 and SQL ServerExpress database and each time i run the phh.info i get lots of error logs like these. 
I also noticed that I do not have these .dll files listed in the 'ext' sub-folder that is in my php folder. Please let someone help so that i can move on. I would appreciate every contribution  here

> [19-Nov-2012 08:44:14 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP\ext\php_msql.dll' - The
>   specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0
>   [19-Nov-2012 08:44:14 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll' - The
>   specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0
>   [19-Nov-2012 08:44:14 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP\ext\php_pdo.dll' - The
>   specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0
>   [19-Nov-2012 08:44:14 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP\ext\php_sqlsrv.dll' - The
>   specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0
>   [19-Nov-2012 08:44:14 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP\ext\php_dblib.dll' - The
>   specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0
>   [19-Nov-2012 08:44:14 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP\ext\php_curl.dll' - The
>   specified procedure could not be found.

I am wondering if that could be the reason why my dropdown is not able to populate from the database
The interesting thing here is that my connection script works fine but the dropdown does not populate and i dont get any error

Comment: Well, to fix "The specified module could not be found because file does not exists" issue is basically simple. Just make it exist :)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have those files in that folder you need to put them there. Search your drive to locate if they are at a different location.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it working now. I guess my problem is that I had more than 2 php files of different versions. So i was able to find the files in one of the ext folders and copied it over and error was fixed. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving this same error.  I downloaded a Dependency Walker program from www.dependencywalker.com and found that the php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll couldn't find php5.dll because I didn't have my php files in my system path.  I added the php install to my path and the warnings went away.